# Own toolbar above website instead of cover? Tampermonkey Userscript

Tags: javascript, css, toolbar, tampermonkey, userscripts

I want to have my own toolbar on specific websites and all in all it works fine. My only problem is, that the toolbar is not above and with this issue I can't use the original navigation. Any suggestions?

[image: without own toolbar]

[image: with own toolbar]

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    // CSS-Stil für die Toolbar und Buttons
    var toolbarStyle = `
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #2ECC71;
        z-index: 9999;
    `;

    var buttonStyle = `
        background-color: #27AE60;
        color: white;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        margin: 0 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
    `;

    // functions for buttons


    // Erstelle die Toolbar
    function createToolbar() {
        var toolbar = document.createElement('div');
        toolbar.style.cssText = toolbarStyle;

        var buttonEmailAn = document.createElement('button');
        buttonEmailAn.textContent = 'E-Mail An';
        buttonEmailAn.style.cssText = buttonStyle;
        buttonEmailAn.addEventListener('click', emailAnFunction);

        // button 2 + 3

        toolbar.appendChild(buttonEmailAn);
        toolbar.appendChild(buttonEmailVon);
        toolbar.appendChild(buttonTicketId);

        // Füge die Toolbar vor der Navigation ein
        document.body.insertBefore(toolbar, document.body.firstChild);
    }

    // Füge die Toolbar hinzu
    createToolbar();
})();
```

I use Google Chrome on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
$('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  alert('it worked');
});
```

```css
/* For demo only */
button{margin-left:5px;}
#myToolbario{display:flex;justify-content:center;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:99.7vw;background:skyblue;border:1px solid blue;}

/* Needed for your solution */
#myToolbario{height:45px; margin-top:-40px; transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out .3s;}
#myToolbario:hover{margin-top:0;}
/* For demo only - StackOverflow specific, just for StackSnippets */
body{margin:0;padding:0;}
```

```html
<div id="myToolbario">
  <button>Email An</button>
  <button>Email Von</button>
  <button>Ticket-ID</button>
</div>
<h1>Move mouse slowly over (hover) light-blue bar</h1>
```

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document); //NOT jQuery

    // inject CSS
    $('body').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', init_css() );



    // Erstelle die Toolbar
    function createToolbar() {
        var toolbar = document.createElement('div');
        toolbar.id = 'myToolbario';

        var buttonEmailAn = document.createElement('button');
        buttonEmailAn.id = 'myButtonio';
        buttonEmailAn.textContent = 'E-Mail An';
        buttonEmailAn.addEventListener('click', emailAnFunction);

        // button 2 + 3

        toolbar.appendChild(buttonEmailAn);
        toolbar.appendChild(buttonEmailVon);
        toolbar.appendChild(buttonTicketId);

        // Füge die Toolbar vor der Navigation ein
        document.body.insertBefore(toolbar, document.body.firstChild);
    }

    // Füge die Toolbar hinzu
    init_css();
    createToolbar();
})();
function init_css(){
return `
    #myToolbario {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 45px;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #2ECC71;
        z-index: 9999;
        margin-top: -40px; /*  ADDED THIS  */
    }
    #myToolbario:hover { margin-top: 0; } /*  ADDED THIS  */
    #myButtonio{
        background-color: #27AE60;
        color: white;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        margin: 0 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
`;
}
```